# How to customize Group Header in DataGrid Grouping?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grouping

I have a DataGrid that looks something like this.

[image]

I have grouped data by Gender. My GroupItem style is

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True"
                      Background="White"
                      Foreground="Black">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I want my Group Header 'Male' and 'Female' to look like 'Gender : Male' and 'Gender : Female' instead of simple plain 'Male' and 'Female'. How can I modify my GroupItem style to achieve this so that every time I group my data in datagrid the group header can appear like GroupHeaderTitle : GroupHeaderValue? or Do I need to change anything other than GroupItem style to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a property `GroupTitle` which represents the desired group title at your view model if you are using MVVM or to your Window code-behind otherwise, then add another TextBlock at the `Expander.Header` which is bound to the `GroupTitle` property, see the following code snippet:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True"
                            Background="White" Foreground="Black">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.GroupTitle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It is a hard coded solution. What if user group by Age? _"every time I group my data in datagrid the group header can appear like GroupHeaderTitle : GroupHeaderValue"_

Comment: @haris: Yeah you are right, I updated my answer, check it now.

Comment: I understand your point but I am allowing user to do multiple nested groupings. Property based solution would again be kind of hard coded solution. I want a generic solution that can work for all nested groupings. In my scenario it is totally up to user whether he wants to group by gender, age or any other column and similarly inside any grouping he can group by any other column

Answer (score 2):

When you add the grouping just supply a converter:

```
// Get the default view
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(...);

// Do the grouping
view.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Gender", new GenderConverter()));

// The converter 
public class GenderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value,
    Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Format("Gender: {0}", value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value,
    Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```